# Implementing cordic in integer arithmetic

Tags: computer-architecture, arithmetic

Referring to [this reference](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eNaCDQAAQBAJ&pg=PR5&dq=elementary%20functions,%20algorithm%20and%20implementations%202nd%20edition&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWgp3L2JnTAhXKiRoKHWNKDXwQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=elementary%20functions%2C%20algorithm%20and%20implementations%202nd%20edition&f=false)...
I'm trying to work out the details of an integer arithmetic implementation of the CORDIC iteration. The CORDIC pseudo-rotations can be summarized as

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{l}
x_{n+1} \\
y_{n+1} \\
z_{n+1}
\end{array} 
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{l}
x_n - d_n2^{-n} y_n \\
x_n + d_n2^{-n} y_n \\
z_n - d_n \omega_n
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Where

$$
\omega_n = \arctan \;2^{-n}
$$

and

$$
d_n = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
1 & z_n \geq 0 \\
-1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

After $k$ iterations the result should be multiplied by the scale factor, name it $K$. However if we find a sequence $\left\{ \alpha_n \right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$
\prod_{j=0}^{+\infty} (1 + \alpha_n2^{-n}) = K
$$

We can achieve the same result of the iteration above by performing

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{l}
x_{n+1} \\
y_{n+1} \\
z_{n+1}
\end{array} 
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{l}
(x_n - d_n2^{-n} y_n)(1+\alpha_n2^{-n}) \\
(x_n + d_n2^{-n} y_n)(1+\alpha_n2^{-n}) \\
z_n - d_n \omega_n
\end{array}
\right).
$$

However I was trying to work out the bitwidth per variable necessary, in order to do that I've tried to convert each computation into a fixed point one.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{l}
x_{n+1} \\
y_{n+1} \\
z_{n+1}
\end{array} 
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{l}
(x_n - d_n2^{-n} y_n)(1+\alpha_n2^{-n}) \\
(x_n + d_n2^{-n} y_n)(1+\alpha_n2^{-n}) \\
z_n - d_n \omega_n
\end{array}
\right) \Rightarrow \left(
\begin{array}{l}
2^{2n}x_{n+1} \\
2^{2n}y_{n+1} \\
2^{2n}z_{n+1}
\end{array} 
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{l}
(2^n x_n - d_n y_n)(2^{n}+\alpha_n) \\
(2^n x_n + d_n y_n)(2^{n}+\alpha_n) \\
(2^{2n}z_n) - d_n (2^{2n} \omega_n)
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Given that a shift of $n$ positions should be repeated for $n = 0 \ldots k$ I would have a total size of

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{k}2n = k(k+1)
$$

So If I wanted to implement CORDIC to compute $k$ bits I would need variables with size of $\Theta(k^2)$ is this correct?